'Canonical' Precedents for Blink (Short-Range Teleportation)
I'm interested in giving a character a rapid-use short-range tactical teleportation ability (inspired by such things as WarCraft Shadowstep and Dishonoured Blink). Obviously a there are different ways that can be done, and there's a decent field for homebrew. But before I do that, I'd like to know examples of similar abilities that are actually published in official materials, to avoid having to reinvent a bicycle, or be better informed before I end up inventing a more customised one.
I've seen the one in Venture City. Are there others?

In unsurprising developments, it's depended on how important teleportation is to the story of both the game and the character with it.
This is not intended as an exhaustive list. Fate's an open system and I can't track down everywhere it's been. This is just a wide spectrum of selections from my personal library.
Super-Powered Fate
The generic book from the authors of Wearing the Cape discusses implementations of various superpowers. As the basic Extra, the core level of superpowers that everybody gets, their Hunted Mutant Jumper (p. 6) gets to move their Athletics+0 in zones without rolling or accounting for obstacles, as long as they can see their destination. A suggested Stunt improvement (p. 15) is that they can also perform an Action at their destination in the same exchange; that is, their free one-zone movement is replaced by line-of-sight teleportation.
Fate System Toolkit
One of the miscellaneous magic toolkit parts in the Toolkit is combat teleportation, 3-4 zones and instantaneous, but costing a Magic Point to use. What's a Magic Point? Spending Refresh on magic-related stunts doesn't consume Fate Points but instead converts them into a number of Magic Points that refresh at the same pace. (The exact conversion rate is left up to how high-magic you want things to get.)
High-Fantasy Magic
Teleportation in this toolkit element is unfortunately underdescribed compared to the other options. It suggests Athletics should be used to contest personal teleportation options but it doesn't provide a lot of details.
Atomic Robo
While not explicitly documented in Atomic Robo, it's completely in-canon to build your own Mega-Stunt for a combat teleporter that starts out "absolutely able to cross human-scale distances and barriers, but", though this would still count as making an Athletics check as your action for the round.
Dresden Files and Starblazer Adventures
Why are these titles together, as disparate as they are? Well, they're both games where personal teleportation on a tactical scale isn't part of the world story, though the concept of teleportation still features. (Okay, in the Dresden Files' case it's travel through the Nevernever or other magical means that actually traverses some manner of physical distance but at a rapid speed. Starblazer Adventures has teleportation but more in the Star Trek sense, strictly as a means for getting on and off the ship.)
So, rules for teleportation on the tactical map are missing entirely, though teleportation or a portal effect can feature as a tactical goal, like needing to hold a position during an evacuation.
Legends of Anglerre
This has an implementation, but as a Fate 3.0 book it will need some adaptation. Combat teleportation is linked to the "Dimensions" specialty skill, an alternate entry into the 3.0 skill pyramid. Two stunts deep in the Dimensions stunt tree (requiring spending a stunt on being able to create stable portals) is combat teleportation, which lets you move to spaces based on the barriers between you and them, which is a baseline of strength 1 for the minimal resistance of the world that stops portals opening up at random. This applies a supplemental action penalty equal to the barrier to any other actions you do that round.
I actually kind of like this one, maybe due to my unreasonable affection for sticking the Fate Core supplemental action penalty into improved capabilities during a conflict. One stunt is probably a good price to pay in Fate Core, on top of whatever establishes your ability to teleport in the first place, since on average characters had twice the stunts in Fate 3.0 and anyway you're probably not thinking of your combat teleporter as someone who started out being able to make stable portals anybody could use and then got more personal.
